# Nant Propety with &amp;

Tags: xml, nant, cdata

I use nant for Build automation. Inside my nant file I include another peroperty file with all the properties I use.

Later I use the existing properties to replace the tokens inside my web.config file

```
<copy file="web.config" tofile="templateed.web.config" overwrite="true">
  <filterchain>
    <expandproperties/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

in the property file i have the following property

```
<property name="url" value="/test?key=1&amp;value=1" />
```

result: `/test?key=1&value=1`

expected: `/test?key=1&amp;value=1`

does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Jürg

Answer (score 2):

`&` means "start of character reference" in XML.

If you want an `&` as data,  you have to use the character reference for it: `&amp;`.

So, if you want `&amp;` as data, you have to replace the `&` with `&amp;` such: `&amp;amp;`.

---

However, what you have *now* appears to be correct for "a URL". So if you want to take that data and put it in another XML file, you should probably let it be decoded to `/test?key=1&value=1` but then encode it for XML when you put it in the new XML.

Comment: I also came up with the solution using `&amp;amp;`. But my build process also creates other property files that are included later. so the transformation happens multiple times. In that case this solution does not work anymore.

Comment: Fix whatever does the transformation so it is XML aware for input and output, not just for input.